# PHP code in cron job is not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, cron, cron-task

I have a PHP script in which I am doing two steps,

1) Deleting all tables from database
2) Restoring default database in that empty database

This code is working properly when I manually run the script by putting the URL but whenever I am running this script with cron job then 1st step is working properly but database is not getting restored.

here is my cron job command ,

```
[php_path] -q /home/[username]/[php_file_path]
```

here is my php script,

```
// Name of the file
$filename = 'sample.sql';
// MySQL host
$mysql_host = 'localhost';
// MySQL username
$mysql_username = 'my_username';
// MySQL password
$mysql_password = 'my_password';
// Database name
$mysql_database = 'my_db_name';


/*----------  Drop All tables From Database  ----------*/



$mysqli = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
$mysqli->query('SET foreign_key_checks = 0');
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SHOW TABLES"))
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
    {
        $mysqli->query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '.$row[0]);
    }
}

$mysqli->query('SET foreign_key_checks = 1');
$mysqli->close();



/*----------  Restore Database From SQL File  ----------*/



$con=mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// ...some PHP code for database "my_db"...

// Change database to "test"
mysqli_select_db($con, $mysql_database);

// ...some PHP code for database "test"...
// Temporary variable, used to store current query
$templine = '';
// Read in entire file
$lines = file($filename);
// Loop through each line
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
// Skip it if it's a comment
if (substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '')
    continue;

// Add this line to the current segment
$templine .= $line;
// If it has a semicolon at the end, it's the end of the query
if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';')
{
    // Perform the query
    mysqli_query($con, $templine) or print('Error performing query \'<strong>' . $templine . '\': ' . mysql_error() . '<br /><br />');
    // Reset temp variable to empty
    $templine = '';
}
}
```

Comment: What user is the cron running under, and does that user have rights to access the file.

Comment: means? I am not getting exact

Comment: After this line `$lines = file($filename);` test `$lines` is not false, like `if ( $lines === false ) { echo "cannot read $filename"; }`

Comment: Also check that you changed the value of `$mysql_database` before you run this line `mysqli_select_db($con, $mysql_database);`